# Django создания строк при инициализации проекта

Tags: django

Допустим есть модель, которая при любом действии с БД, когда данные удаляются, заново создавала в себе данные заданные по дефолту, но так же могла предоставлять возможность пользователю вносить свои правки.

```
class SubOperations(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Допустим есть список операций, который нужно добавить при миграции бд.

```
suboper_default = [
    {'1': 'Create'},
    {'2': 'Update'},
    {'3': 'Hide'},
    {'4': 'Delete'},
]
```

Можно ли добавить логику создания такой модели через init метод ? Или есть более правильное решение задачи.

```
def __init__(self):
    for i in suboper_default:
        SubOperations.objects.create(i.values())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можете сделать обработчик сигнала `post_delete`, `post_migrate` на модель `SubOperations`, который будет проверять БД и создать данные при необходимости.